how should i sync github actions to have a centralize workflow
i am trying out github actions recently and was previously using gitlab cicd.
in gitlab cicd I could have a centralize repository that contains all the gitlab cicd yaml like below:

does github actions have similar feature where I could have a centralize workflow that could be used for all app repo?

Sure, you can store your GitHub workflows in a central repo and call them inside your .yaml:
jobs:
  call-workflow-in-another-repo:
    uses: octo-org/another-repo/.github/workflows/workflow.yml@v1

See here more info.
